# Why begin/rescue/else behaves differently on 1.9.2 and 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, exception, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-1.8

I am working with the method `mm`. In ruby 1.9.2 it behaves weird, instead of the expected result `1.9.2=>10` I am getting

```
ELSE **
1.9.2=>8
```

**Any idea of what is going on?**

```
class A

 def mm(data)
   begin
     send_len = data
     return send_len
   rescue Exception
     STDOUT.write("Rescue *#{$!}*\n")
   else
     STDOUT.write("ELSE *#{$!}*\n")
   end
 end

end # class A

a = A.new
print "#{RUBY_VERSION}=>#{a.mm(10)}\n"
```

With 1.8.7 I get the expected result:

```
1.8.7=>10
```

Comment: In have read "Exceptions" on page 355 of book "Programming Ruby 1.9" by Dave Thomas et al but not useful...

Comment: @Evgeny Shadchnev Why did you mention 1.8.6 in the title? I changed it to 1.8.7.

Comment: @sawa Sorry, a typo. You are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an [open bug in Ruby](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4473). There is a discussion, though, whether it should behave like it behaved in 1.8 or as it does in 1.9.

Matz, the author of Ruby, [believes that it should behave as in 1.8](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1440863#1004370).

Comment: To clarify, the reason it's returning 8 instead of the expected 10 is that `STDOUT.write("ELSE *#{$!}*\n")` is the last line to be actually executed (instead of the `return`) and you get returned the value from that (which is the number of bytes written, or 8 in this case).

Comment: Thanks Evgeny. I think so too. I thought it was a bug...now  I am sure.